# How to read list in HTML with Thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring, list, thymeleaf

I have this code in html:

```
<form id="tableForm" th:object="${teachersLessonsRows}" method="post">
    <table class="table">
        <caption>My lessons</caption>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Student's Name</th>
            <th>Lesson's day</th>
            <th>Estimate</th>
        </tr>
        <th:block th:each="teachersLessonsRow, i:${teachersLessonsRows}">
            <tr th:each="studentEstimates, j:${teachersLessonsRow.getStudentEstimates()}">
                <td th:text="${teachersLessonsRow.getLessonName()}"></td>
                <td th:text="${studentEstimates.getStudentName()}"></td>
                <td th:text="'#'+${studentEstimates.getDayNum()}"></td>
                <td>
                    <input th:id="${teachersLessonsRow.getLessonName()+' '+studentEstimates.getStudentName()+' '+studentEstimates.getDayNum()}"
                           type="text" th:text="${studentEstimates.estimate}" onkeyup="checkEdit(this.id);"
                           th:field="*{add(${teachersLessonsRow})}">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </th:block>
    </table>
```

and when i launch my code in InteliJ i've got this error:
ERROR 12079 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine             : [THYMELEAF][http-nio-8080-exec-8] Exception processing template "lessonsTeacher": Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.spring5.processor.SpringInputGeneralFieldTagProcessor' (template: "lessonsTeacher" - line 53, col 36)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'add(${teachersLessonsRow})' of bean class [java.util.ArrayList]: Bean property 'add(${teachersLessonsRow})' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?

I understand that this row th:field="*{add(${teachersLessonsRow})}" has error but where?

About my class in Java:

```
public class TeachersLessonsRow {
    private String lessonName;
    private List<StudentEstimate> studentEstimates;

    TeachersLessonsRow() {}

    public TeachersLessonsRow(String lessonName, List<StudentEstimate> studentEstimates) {
        this.lessonName = lessonName;
        this.studentEstimates = studentEstimates;
    }

    public String getLessonName() {
        return lessonName;
    }

    public void setEventName(String eventName) {
        this.lessonName = eventName;
    }


    public List<StudentEstimate> getStudentEstimates() {
        return studentEstimates;
    }

    public void setStudentEstimates(List<StudentEstimate> studentEstimates) {
        this.studentEstimates = studentEstimates;
    }
}

public class StudentEstimate {
    private String studentName;
    private int dayNum;
    private int estimate;

    public StudentEstimate() {}

    public StudentEstimate(String studentName, int estimate) {
        this.studentName = studentName;
        this.estimate = estimate;
    }

    public StudentEstimate(String studentName, int dayNum, int estimate) {
        this.dayNum = dayNum;
        this.studentName = studentName;
        this.estimate = estimate;
    }

    public String getStudentName() {
        return studentName;
    }

    public void setStudentName(String studentName) {
        this.studentName = studentName;
    }

    public int getEstimate() {
        return estimate;
    }

    public void setEstimate(int estimate) {
        this.estimate = estimate;
    }

    public int getDayNum() {
        return dayNum;
    }

    public void setDayNum(int dayNum) {
        this.dayNum = dayNum;
    }
}
```

When i don't add this error-row i don't have a questions and problems. But when i try to get my list in @PostMapping i have this error. In my Controller i have this:

```
@PostMapping(URL_TEACHER + URL_LESSONS)
public ModelAndView teacherSearchLesson(
        ModelMap modelMap,
        @RequestParam(value = "les_input", required = false) String lesson,
        @RequestParam(value = "fml_input", required = false) String fml,
        @RequestParam(value = "grp_input", required = false) String grp,
        @RequestParam(value = "crs_input", required = false) String crs,
        @ModelAttribute(value = "teachersLessonsRows") TableForm form
) {
    System.out.println(form);

    TeachersLessonsRow teachersLessonsRow = null;
    List<TeachersLessonsRow> teachersLessonsRows = new ArrayList<>();

    ...

    modelMap.addAttribute("teachersLessonsRows", teachersLessonsRows);
    return new ModelAndView("lessonsTeacher", modelMap);
}
```

TableForm is class which contains List teachersLessonsRows and getter and setter for this list.

Comment: Whatever you add in th:field is referencing back to a java property in your bean.  What are you trying to do with that input field?

Comment: Ohh... Well, in my idea, i want to read fields and update in my db this data.
Wait, i describe my html...

Comment: I have html-page with table(with columns: lessonName, studentName, dayNum, Estimate) and with Edit-button which activated when i change one or more fields in Estimate column. And... I want save edited rows and submit it to my method in Java and update my db. How to update in my update i know, how to do the rest?